# Swagger/CORs questions with Grizzly server

Tags: java, swagger, grizzly

for various reasons I'm trying to replace the jetty server on my jersey rest api with grizzly.

At the moment my code is pretty simple

```
public class Server {
    private static URI getBaseUri() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(8080).build();
    }

    private static final URI BASE_URI = getBaseUri();

    protected static HttpServer startServer() throws IOException {
        final Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

        initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "my.package.resources");
        initParams.put("com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing", "my.package.resources");

        System.out.println("Starting Grizzly server ....");

        return GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(BASE_URI, initParams);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer httpServer = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));

        System.in.read();
        httpServer.stop();
    }

}
```

Which seems to work fine, however after much googling I am struggling to work out two things:

1) For my Jetty server to work, I needed to add in a CORs filter - I can't think of a reason why I wouldn't still need to do this

2) I'd like to mount the swagger ui to something like blahblah:8080/swagger-ui

Does anyone know how to do these things? (or point me in the direction of an example?)

Comment: please take a look at this sample, it should help you to understand how to register servlet filters. Regarding the swagger, is it represented as a servlet? if yes - just register it programmatically. https://github.com/oleksiys/samples/blob/master/grizzly-jersey2-jsp-sample/src/main/java/eu/lucubratory/jrjf1/Main.java

Comment: Cool, thanks I will have a look (yes a servlet is probably the best way to show the swagger ui)